# Difference between shell and meterpreter?

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter, cmd

What exactly is the diffrence between meterpreter `reverse_shell` and any other non-meterpreter reverse shells?

1) The non-meterpreter reverse shell: `windows/shell/reverse_tcp`

2) Meterpreter: `windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp`

Comment: Have you read the documentation for what meterpreter is?

Answer (score 3):

Basically `windows/shell/reverse_tcp` will give you a reverse shell->basically command prompt.

and `windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` this will will you a reverse meterpreter session.A meterpreter session contains more than just a shell such as screenshot commands/Webcam grab.Things like that cannot be done from pure command execution.

Also.Instead of just asking wouldn't it be better to just try it out?Or better yet read their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**What is a reverse shell?**

A reverse shell is a type of shell in which the target machine communicates back to the attacking machine. The attacking machine has a listener port on which it receives the connection, which by using, code or command execution is achieved.

**What is meterpreter?**
The meterpreter/reverse_tcp is a staged payload used to gain meterpreter access to a compromised system.

Comment: It comes down that any payloads that are not in the meterpreter directory, that payloads are not evaluated the way meterpreter works.